# Tuning Tidymodels’ Recipe and Model Parameters Simultaneously

Tags: r, tidymodels

We can use Tidymodels to tune both recipe parameters and model parameters simultaneously, right?  I'm struggling to understand what corrective action I should take based on the message, *Error: Some tuning parameters require finalization but there are recipe parameters that require tuning. Please use `parameters()` to finalize the parameter ranges.”*  Any help would be most appreciated.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidymodels))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(themis))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(finetune))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(doParallel))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(titanic))

registerDoParallel()

set.seed(123)


train.df <- titanic_train %>% 
  mutate(Survived = factor(ifelse(Survived == 1, 'Y', 'N')),
         Pclass = factor(Pclass, ordered = TRUE),
         Sex = factor(Sex),
         Embarked = factor(ifelse(Embarked == '', NA, Embarked))) %>% 
  select(-c(Name, Ticket, Cabin))


summary(train.df)
#>   PassengerId    Survived Pclass      Sex           Age            SibSp      
#>  Min.   :  1.0   N:549    1:216   female:314   Min.   : 0.42   Min.   :0.000  
#>  1st Qu.:223.5   Y:342    2:184   male  :577   1st Qu.:20.12   1st Qu.:0.000  
#>  Median :446.0            3:491                Median :28.00   Median :0.000  
#>  Mean   :446.0                                 Mean   :29.70   Mean   :0.523  
#>  3rd Qu.:668.5                                 3rd Qu.:38.00   3rd Qu.:1.000  
#>  Max.   :891.0                                 Max.   :80.00   Max.   :8.000  
#>                                                NA's   :177                    
#>      Parch             Fare        Embarked  
#>  Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :  0.00   C   :168  
#>  1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:  7.91   Q   : 77  
#>  Median :0.0000   Median : 14.45   S   :644  
#>  Mean   :0.3816   Mean   : 32.20   NA's:  2  
#>  3rd Qu.:0.0000   3rd Qu.: 31.00             
#>  Max.   :6.0000   Max.   :512.33             
#> 


cv.folds <- vfold_cv(train.df, v = 4, strata = Survived)

cv.folds
#> #  4-fold cross-validation using stratification 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   splits            id   
#>   <list>            <chr>
#> 1 <split [667/224]> Fold1
#> 2 <split [668/223]> Fold2
#> 3 <split [669/222]> Fold3
#> 4 <split [669/222]> Fold4

#########################################################

# Logistic Regression Model -- This Works
#   Tuning Recipe Parameters: Yes
#   Tuning Model Hyperparameters: No
  
recipe.logistic.regression <- 
  recipe(Survived ~ ., data = train.df) %>% 
  update_role(PassengerId, new_role = 'ID') %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>% 
  step_impute_knn(all_predictors(), neighbors = tune()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_downsample(Survived, seed = 456)

spec.logistic.regression <- 
  logistic_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("glm")

wf.logistic.regression <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(recipe.logistic.regression) %>% 
  add_model(spec.logistic.regression)

wf.logistic.regression
#> == Workflow ====================================================================
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: logistic_reg()
#> 
#> -- Preprocessor ----------------------------------------------------------------
#> 4 Recipe Steps
#> 
#> * step_dummy()
#> * step_impute_knn()
#> * step_normalize()
#> * step_downsample()
#> 
#> -- Model -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Logistic Regression Model Specification (classification)
#> 
#> Computational engine: glm

rs.logistic.regression <- tune_race_anova(
  wf.logistic.regression,
  resamples = cv.folds,
  grid = 25,
  metrics = metric_set(accuracy),
  control = control_race(verbose = TRUE, verbose_elim = TRUE,
                         parallel_over = "everything",
                         save_pred = TRUE,
                         save_workflow = TRUE)
)
#> i Racing will maximize the accuracy metric.
#> i Resamples are analyzed in a random order.
#> i Fold4:  1 eliminated;  9 candidates remain.

show_best(rs.logistic.regression)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#>   neighbors .metric  .estimator  mean     n std_err .config              
#>       <int> <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>                
#> 1         9 accuracy binary     0.791     4  0.0193 Preprocessor01_Model1
#> 2         2 accuracy binary     0.788     4  0.0186 Preprocessor08_Model1
#> 3         4 accuracy binary     0.788     4  0.0190 Preprocessor09_Model1
#> 4         1 accuracy binary     0.787     4  0.0205 Preprocessor05_Model1
#> 5        10 accuracy binary     0.787     4  0.0205 Preprocessor10_Model1

#########################################################
  
# Random Forest Model A -- This Works
#   Tuning Recipe Parameters: No
#   Tuning Model Hyperparameters: Yes
  
recipe.random.forest.a <- 
  recipe(Survived ~ ., data = train.df) %>% 
  update_role(PassengerId, new_role = 'ID') %>% 
  step_impute_knn(all_predictors(), 
                  neighbors = 5) %>%  # <-- Manually setting value for neighbors
  step_downsample(Survived, seed = 456)

spec.random.forest.a <-
  rand_forest(mtry = tune(),
              min_n = tune(),
              trees = tune()) %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  set_engine("ranger")

wf.random.forest.a <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(recipe.random.forest.a) %>% 
  add_model(spec.random.forest.a)

wf.random.forest.a
#> == Workflow ====================================================================
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: rand_forest()
#> 
#> -- Preprocessor ----------------------------------------------------------------
#> 2 Recipe Steps
#> 
#> * step_impute_knn()
#> * step_downsample()
#> 
#> -- Model -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Random Forest Model Specification (classification)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   mtry = tune()
#>   trees = tune()
#>   min_n = tune()
#> 
#> Computational engine: ranger

rs.random.forest.a <- tune_race_anova(
  wf.random.forest.a,
  resamples = cv.folds,
  grid = 25,
  metrics = metric_set(accuracy),
  control = control_race(verbose = TRUE, verbose_elim = TRUE,
                         parallel_over = "everything",
                         save_pred = TRUE,
                         save_workflow = TRUE)
)
#> i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry
#> i Racing will maximize the accuracy metric.
#> i Resamples are analyzed in a random order.
#> i Fold4:  4 eliminated; 21 candidates remain.

show_best(rs.random.forest.a)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 9
#>    mtry trees min_n .metric  .estimator  mean     n std_err .config             
#>   <int> <int> <int> <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1     4   837    18 accuracy binary     0.818     4 0.00685 Preprocessor1_Model~
#> 2     4  1968    16 accuracy binary     0.817     4 0.00738 Preprocessor1_Model~
#> 3     4  1439    25 accuracy binary     0.817     4 0.00664 Preprocessor1_Model~
#> 4     3  1769    10 accuracy binary     0.816     4 0.0130  Preprocessor1_Model~
#> 5     3  1478    13 accuracy binary     0.816     4 0.0109  Preprocessor1_Model~

#########################################################
  
# Random Forest Model B -- This Does Not Work
#   Tuning Recipe Parameters: Yes
#   Tuning Model Hyperparameters: Yes
  
recipe.random.forest.b <- 
  recipe(Survived ~ ., data = train.df) %>% 
  update_role(PassengerId, new_role = 'ID') %>% 
  step_impute_knn(all_predictors(), 
                  neighbors = tune()) %>%  # <-- Tuning neighbors
  step_downsample(Survived, seed = 456)

spec.random.forest.b <-
  rand_forest(mtry = tune(),
              min_n = tune(),
              trees = tune()) %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  set_engine("ranger")

wf.random.forest.b <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(recipe.random.forest.b) %>% 
  add_model(spec.random.forest.b)

wf.random.forest.b
#> == Workflow ====================================================================
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: rand_forest()
#> 
#> -- Preprocessor ----------------------------------------------------------------
#> 2 Recipe Steps
#> 
#> * step_impute_knn()
#> * step_downsample()
#> 
#> -- Model -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Random Forest Model Specification (classification)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   mtry = tune()
#>   trees = tune()
#>   min_n = tune()
#> 
#> Computational engine: ranger

rs.random.forest.b <- tune_race_anova(
  wf.random.forest.b,
  resamples = cv.folds,
  grid = 25,
  metrics = metric_set(accuracy),
  control = control_race(verbose = TRUE, verbose_elim = TRUE,
                         parallel_over = "everything",
                         save_pred = TRUE,
                         save_workflow = TRUE)
)
#> Error: Some tuning parameters require finalization but there are recipe parameters that require tuning. Please use `parameters()` to finalize the parameter ranges.

#########################################################

sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
#> [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
#> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
#> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
#> [8] base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] titanic_0.1.0      doParallel_1.0.16  iterators_1.0.13   foreach_1.5.1     
#>  [5] finetune_0.1.0     themis_0.1.4       yardstick_0.0.8    workflowsets_0.1.0
#>  [9] workflows_0.2.3    tune_0.1.6         rsample_0.1.0      recipes_0.1.16    
#> [13] parsnip_0.1.7      modeldata_0.1.1    infer_0.5.4        dials_0.0.9       
#> [17] scales_1.1.1       broom_0.7.9        tidymodels_0.1.3   forcats_0.5.1     
#> [21] stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_1.0.7        purrr_0.3.4        readr_2.0.0       
#> [25] tidyr_1.1.3        tibble_3.1.3       ggplot2_3.3.5      tidyverse_1.3.1   
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] minqa_1.2.4        colorspace_2.0-2   ellipsis_0.3.2     class_7.3-19      
#>  [5] fs_1.5.0           rstudioapi_0.13    listenv_0.8.0      furrr_0.2.3       
#>  [9] ParamHelpers_1.14  prodlim_2019.11.13 fansi_0.5.0        lubridate_1.7.10  
#> [13] ranger_0.13.1      xml2_1.3.2         codetools_0.2-18   splines_4.1.0     
#> [17] knitr_1.33         jsonlite_1.7.2     nloptr_1.2.2.2     pROC_1.17.0.1     
#> [21] dbplyr_2.1.1       compiler_4.1.0     httr_1.4.2         backports_1.2.1   
#> [25] assertthat_0.2.1   Matrix_1.3-4       cli_3.0.1          htmltools_0.5.1.1 
#> [29] tools_4.1.0        gtable_0.3.0       glue_1.4.2         RANN_2.6.1        
#> [33] parallelMap_1.5.1  fastmatch_1.1-3    Rcpp_1.0.7         cellranger_1.1.0  
#> [37] styler_1.5.1       DiceDesign_1.9     vctrs_0.3.8        nlme_3.1-152      
#> [41] timeDate_3043.102  mlr_2.19.0         gower_0.2.2        xfun_0.25         
#> [45] globals_0.14.0     lme4_1.1-27.1      rvest_1.0.1        lifecycle_1.0.0   
#> [49] future_1.21.0      MASS_7.3-54        ipred_0.9-11       hms_1.1.0         
#> [53] BBmisc_1.11        yaml_2.2.1         rpart_4.1-15       stringi_1.7.3     
#> [57] highr_0.9          checkmate_2.0.0    lhs_1.1.1          boot_1.3-28       
#> [61] hardhat_0.1.6      lava_1.6.9         rlang_0.4.11       pkgconfig_2.0.3   
#> [65] evaluate_0.14      lattice_0.20-44    tidyselect_1.1.1   parallelly_1.27.0 
#> [69] plyr_1.8.6         magrittr_2.0.1     R6_2.5.0           generics_0.1.0    
#> [73] DBI_1.1.1          pillar_1.6.2       haven_2.4.3        withr_2.4.2       
#> [77] survival_3.2-11    nnet_7.3-16        ROSE_0.0-4         modelr_0.1.8      
#> [81] crayon_1.4.1       unbalanced_2.0     utf8_1.2.2         tzdb_0.1.2        
#> [85] rmarkdown_2.10     grid_4.1.0         readxl_1.3.1       data.table_1.14.0 
#> [89] FNN_1.1.3          reprex_2.0.1       digest_0.6.27      munsell_0.5.0     
#> [93] GPfit_1.0-8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The problem is that `mtry` depends on the **number of columns** that are going into the random forest, but your recipe is tunable so there are no guarantees about how many columns are coming in. I would either a) not tune the random forest (just set `trees = 1e3` and you'll likely be fine) or b) use your domain knowledge of the data to [create a tuning grid](https://www.tmwr.org/grid-search.html#grids) with values for `mtry` that make sense (instead of saying `grid = 25`).